# How do you know when you are 90% sure or 99% sure?

Tags: self-study, confidence-interval, uncertainty

The problem is a follow up to my previous one, so a lot of contextual data can be found at:
[how to find 10th, 50th, 90th percentile of a uniformly distributed data for all cases?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/449911/how-to-find-10th-50th-90th-percentile-of-a-uniformly-distributed-data-for-all)

But this is a very different question, so I'm asking in a separate post.

So basically we have a population that's consuming food at certain rate, and the population also decays and rises in a certain rate.

Now we have a factory that produces rice between 3-7 lbs every week. We can open up another factory to double our production capacity.

**The question is:**

In the next 10 months, do we need a 2nd factory? If so, when do we need 2nd factory to start producing in order to be 90% sure that we will not have a shortage in the next 10 months? What about 99% sure?

**My additional questions are:**

Again, I'm not sure if this asking for confidence interval? Am I on the right track? But even confidence interval of 90% doesn't mean 90% sure right? How can I **be 90% sure**?

***Below are the data/context from my other/previous post:***

Here are some **key data to use for calculation**:

1. initial population is 100, and average food consumption per person is 5lbs of rice each week
2. 1~2% of population dies off every month
3. 20~40 is added to population every month
4. average rice consumption per person increases by 0~2.5% weekly

**Assumptions:**

- assume all random variables are independent
- assume all variables are uniformly distributed across the given range.

Comment: Do you know the rates you've mentioned exactly?

Comment: @DemetriPananos it's all in the other post i've mentioned (linked too). I have copied and pasted all the contextual data/rates over to this post as well for your convenience.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my simulation repeated 3000 times of how much rice consumption we can expect for the whole population for a given week. At week 0 we initialize the population, the simulation starts from week 1 to week 40 (10 months).

```
set.seed(420)
res=vector("list",3000)
for (i in 1:3000) {
  pop=100
  con=rep(5,100)
  for (j in seq(1,10*4)) {
    pop=round(pop-runif(1,0.01,0.02)/4*pop+runif(1,20,40)/4)
    con=c(con+con*runif(length(con),0,0.025),rep(5,pop-length(con)))
    res[[i]]=list(res[[i]],list(sum(con)))
  }
}
res2=do.call(rbind,lapply(res,unlist))

res3=apply(res2,2,quantile,c(0.9,0.99))
colnames(res3)=seq(1,10*4)

           1        2        3       4        5        6        7        8        9       10       11
90% 551.3355 598.1253 644.6377 688.529 733.2504 780.8840 826.3126 872.5555 920.7182 968.0577 1015.654
99% 556.2059 603.9017 654.8735 702.890 748.3345 797.2045 846.8235 895.3333 943.0971 994.0324 1042.126
          12       13       14       15       16       17       18       19       20       21       22
90% 1063.278 1111.997 1161.249 1210.404 1260.630 1309.732 1361.216 1412.829 1464.738 1517.037 1569.328
99% 1090.642 1139.992 1189.153 1243.520 1293.424 1344.706 1395.561 1448.679 1502.453 1557.094 1610.741
          23       24       25       26       27       28       29       30       31       32       33
90% 1622.136 1676.272 1729.321 1785.044 1840.421 1895.693 1951.390 2009.389 2065.540 2123.635 2183.095
99% 1664.700 1718.072 1774.654 1829.158 1883.617 1939.543 1997.133 2056.717 2115.025 2173.715 2236.004
          34       35       36       37       38       39       40
90% 2242.781 2302.051 2364.158 2424.867 2486.894 2549.348 2611.736
99% 2293.333 2354.147 2416.016 2476.878 2538.198 2603.070 2665.921
```

These are the 90 and 99 % values for weekly rice consumption for the whole population. What remains unclear is how much rice do you produce now (per week). Based on that you can figure out where your production falls below the 90 or 99 % value for which week.